# How to set app-only permissions to a list with Graph?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

In the GUI I can give an app access to a specific list via the `/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`
[image: app access to list]

How do I do this with Graph API or the SharePoint REST API?

I did some research, but so far I only found solution for site-level access via de `/sites/{siteId}/permissions` endpoint. This doesn't seem to be available for lists.

Answer (score 0):

When using `appregnew.aspx`, you are using the SharePoint Add-in app registration model. This registers apps with Azure Access Control Services (ACS), not Azure Active Directory (AD). You can use apps registered with Azure ACS with the SharePoint Rest API and the SharePoint Client Object Model (CSOM), but you cannot use them with Microsoft Graph. For Microsoft Graph you must register the app with Azure AD.

I did a quick search and this as the only resource I found that demonstrated the app registration process. Hopefully it's enough to enable you to move forward.

[Access SharePoint Sites/files using MS Graph API via AAD App registration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmWejAg2cfA)

Comment: Currently we kinda mix the two, register the app in Azure and grant access via de appinv.aspx to one site or library. The guy in the video skips the interesting part by granting access to all sites across the tenant.